# "Unexpected character" error when invoking Neo4j rest endpoint with curl

Tags: rest, curl, neo4j

I am facing a problem when invoking a cypher query on my local running Neo4j 3.0 via curl from my windows command line:

```
curl -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json -d '{"statements":[{"statement":"match (a:T_APPLICATION) RETURN a.id, a.name"}]}'  http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
```

The response I got back on the windows command line is:

```
{"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat","message ":"Unable to deserialize request: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected  a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [ Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@23482f11; line: 1, column: 2]"}]}
```

Maybe I missed a character somewhere or need to escape something. Hope someone can help me on this.
Best
Markus

Comment: Your query works fine on my Mac, I think this has to do with how the command line is parsed on Windows. Are you doing this from cmd.exe, bash, something else?

Comment: You can work around this by putting the JSON body in a file, and change the `-d` parameter to `-d @body.json`.

Comment: Hi @FrankPavageau . I am executing from cmd.exe. I tried it in parallel from chrome extension "DHC by Restlet", and it works in that environment. So I think you are right , the root cause is how windows parses he command line. I will try to put the json in a file as you suggested.

Comment: I tried this 
`curl -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json -d "&w:\body.json"  http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit`

Result is again an error:
`{"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat","message":"Unable to deserialize request: Unexpected character ('&' (code 38)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@32cec9c4; line: 1, column: 2]"}]}`

Comment: I found a solution that is working under windows

`curl -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json   -d "{"""statements""":[{"""statement""":"""match(a:T_APPLICATION) RETURN a.id, a.name"""}]}" http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit`

Comment: Like I wrote, to read the content of a file instead of providing the body on the command line, you replace the body by `@body.json`: `-d @body.json`. I don't know where you got your `&w:\` syntax.